# Salesforcce Email Template and flow

Tags: visual-workflow, email-template

I have an email template in public folder of sandbox, earlier it was going through a email alert. Now I am using a email action in flow because I required some field from related record which wasn't showing in email fields.
So if I get template id in get records and pass it in email action will it require any object or some permission to person who triggers the flow, for that email template id.

The email templates are already existing ones so want to use them in the email action. Just need suggestion if I get id of email template in flow, and pass it to email action will it give some error related to permission of email template in public flower for certain users.

Comment: Welcome to SFSE!. Please see [ask] on getting the most from the community.  This question is confusing and should be rewritten